# EBNF Definition of Identifier

Tags: bnf, ebnf

The EBNF definition of an identifier is `(a-zA-Z, _ ){a-zA-Z0-9, _ }`. Can someone explain this definition and give me a valid identifier by this definition.

Comment: That just means it has to start with an alphabet or an underscore, followed by any number of alphanumeric characters and underscores. `_` is valid, `_a_var` is valid, `_____` is also valid, `aVar_` is valid as well, `9_var` isn't

Comment: @Alex thanks , got the explanation. this string _4H_2 is also valid

Comment: Strictly, there's no way to tell from the information given. The rule uses 3 undefined non-terminals (`a-zA-Z`, `_`, `a-zA-Z0-9`) (see ISO 14977 — the standard [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form)). Further, the commas indicate sequencing, the parentheses grouping, and the braces repeatable material. Assuming that the non-terminals expand to `[a-zA-Z]` and `[a-zA-Z0-9]` in regex notation, then identifiers start with a letter and an underscore, and continue with alternating alphanumerics and underscores. Thus `a_` and `a_A_` are valid; `a`, and `_2_` are not.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) like languages differ a lot.
Normally I would define something like this:

```
letter = "a" | "b" | ... | "z" | "A" | ... | "Z";
digit = "0" | "1" | "2" | ... | "9";
identifier = letter , { letter | digit | "_" } ;
```

Your form looks like a mixture of [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) and [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).
It is hard to tell what this means if I don't know which language we are talking about.

But by pure guessing, I would say it describes a C-like identifier (e.g. variable name) like "myVar_0123ab".
The identifier has to start with a letter, or an underline '_', followed by letters, underlines and digits.